# VBA - Loop Through Array, Assign Value to Different Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm creating two arrays based on a range in my Excel sheet:
AdjustedProductionValues,
ProductionTargetValues

I'm creating a third array to hold new values:
FinalProductionValues

I want to loop through AdjustedProductionValues; if the value is 0 I want to assign the value of ProductionTargetValues to a new array FinalProductionValues. Otherwise, I want to assign the value of AdjustedProductionValues to FinalProductionValues.

I keep getting an error of Subscript out of range. I've tried ReDim a couple different ways with no success. I get the error at the If statement.

How do I fix this?

```
Sub TEST()

    Dim AdjustedProductionValues()          As Variant
    Dim ProductionTargetValues()            As Variant
    Dim FinalProductionValues()             As Variant
    ReDim FinalProductionValues(1 To 1)     As Variant
    Dim i                                   As Integer

    'Assigning Adjusted Production and Production Target numbers into lists
    Worksheets("SUMMARY").Activate

    AdjustedProductionValues = Range(Range("E35"), Range("E35").End(xlToRight))
    ProductionTargetValues = Range(Range("E34"), Range("E34").End(xlToRight))

    'checking each Adjusted Production value
    'if it's 0 then assigns the Adjusted Production value to a new list
    'if it's not 0 it assignes the Production Target to the new list

    For i = 0 To UBound(AdjustedProductionValues)
        ReDim Preserve FinalProductionValues(1 To UBound(FinalProductionValues) + 1) As Variant
        If AdjustedProductionValues(i) = 0 Then
            FinalProductionValues(UBound(FinalProductionValues)) = ProductionTargetValues(i)
        Else
            FinalProductionValues(UBound(FinalProductionValues)) = AdjustedProductionValues(i)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

**UPDATE W/ FIX**
I fixed my code with this:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(AdjustedProductionValues, 2)
    ReDim Preserve FinalProductionValues(1 To UBound(FinalProductionValues) + 1) As Variant
    If AdjustedProductionValues(1, i) = 0 Then
        FinalProductionValues(UBound(FinalProductionValues)) = ProductionTargetValues(1, i)
    Else
        FinalProductionValues(UBound(FinalProductionValues)) = AdjustedProductionValues(1, i)
    End If
Next i
```

I checked my work by using the following:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
Dim NumRows As Long
Dim NumCols As Long
NumRows = 1
NumCols = UBound(FinalProductionValues, 1) - LBound(FinalProductionValues, 1) + 1
Range("A1").Resize(NumRows, NumCols).Value = FinalProductionValues
```

Got help checking my code with [this link.](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: Arrays obtained for a Range's Value property (as you are doing) are 2D, so for a row as in your code, use `If AdjustedProductionValues(1, i) = 0 Then`.  Similar for `FinalProductionValues`

Comment: 2D and *one-based*, not zero-based, so `i` should start at 1 not at 0

Comment: Thank you for the help! I got everything working!